# Ubuntu Samba share not writable by Apache on another machine

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I have a basic shared folder on a ubuntu desktop (VM) that I want everyone to have 100% read/write to it. I can set this up, and use a mac to connect and mount the folder but logging in as the ubuntu user.

MAMP is running on the OSX machine (same machine). The volume is mounted at /Volumes/uploads on the Mac. When I try and upload some files through Apache.PHP, which then move to the mounted volume it says it is a permission error.

The user in Apache is the same as the user who is mounting the volume (in this case just admin).

As it's mounted as admin, and apache is running as admin, and I can write files to it in Finder, I was wondering if I have missed something in the Samba config or the Apache config?

Comment: Can you add the exact error from the apache log?

Comment: I don't get anything showing up in PHP or Apache logs, except when I initially try and change the CMS (Drupal's) private file path to the volume it will say `[Thu May 09 18:00:10 2013] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store`

Answer (score 1):

It was a conflict in paths. uploads was already created under Volumes and it was uploads-1 - but of course the name is "uploads" in finder.

Note to all: Always check your paths!!